# Please could somebody explain why my Bootstrap doesn't apply?

Tags: html, class, bootstrap-4, nav

I am trying to build my first webpage with Bootstrap, but the Bootstrap code I have added appears to be half responsive (e.g. the navbar seems to know it's been provided some kind of Bootstrap class, but other classes such as navbar-dark do nothing). I have also had to remove the bullet points from my ul myself even though the tutorial I'm following hasn't.
I feel as though my issue is how Bootstrap is linked to my HTML file, but remain stumped.
Thank you in advance. Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>White Rose Crew Company Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="./recources/css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutUs">ABOUT US</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#ourWork">OUR WORK</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#theCrew">THE CREW</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contactUs">CONTACT US</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
      
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check [the official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/)?

Comment: As far as I can see I have linked everything correctly. If I remove the class .navbar from my nav element, the page changes dramatically, however if I remove/add any of the other classes in that element nothing happens. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an old version of Bootstrap.
change the version to 4.4 to make this work

Comment: I feel like my problem is not understanding why there are so many different cdn providers, versions of Bootstrap and why you would use one over another. I also feel like my coursework is telling me to put the links at the end of my body element, whilst on here people are telling me to put them in the head element. Everybody telling me to use different versions and CDN providers has confused me further. Is there any chance you can just show me the three link/scripts I need to apply and where to put them? Thank you.

Comment: @Lil'BigBoy every developer can use any cdn (jQuery use stackpath its something like advertising for stackpath), it can affect the speed in rare cases. On head tag you must use only scripts and styles witch important to load before the page loaded, fewer styles and scripts is better.

Comment: So which CDN is irrelevant as long as I use one.

Legendary, mate. Big up ya'self. One Love. Peace Up. A-Town down.

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap 3.4.1 you need to use

`https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css`

For bootstrap 4 you need to use

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

You write on bootstrap 4 syntax but link to bootstrap 3

For bootstrap 5 (latest beta) you need to use

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

[Check documentation page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: I think my problem stems from none of my coursework explaining why there are so many different href's to Bootstrap libraries. Every website I visit tells me to insert different links (jsdelivr, maxcdn, ajax ect. ect. ect.).

Are they for different libraries? Do I have to match scripts/links to the same provider (i.e. link to bootstrap, script for bootstrap and link to jquery all from jsdelivr?)

Comment: @Lil'BigBoy first about versions: check this page [bootstrap 3 vs bootstrap 4 (flexbox)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-bootstrap-3-and-bootstrap-4/?ref=lbp) for 4vs5 check [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-bootstrap-4-and-bootstrap-5/) In [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) you can switch between versions in right top corner. You can see what official cdn did they use. jQuery provided by StackPath, bootstrap by jsdelivr, no matter what do you use, better use cdn from the official documentation

Answer (score 0):

To apply bootstrap whichever version you want to apply please pick correct css file from any online CDN libraries. e.g.
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutUs">ABOUT US</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#ourWork">OUR WORK</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#theCrew">THE CREW</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contactUs">CONTACT US</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
      
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have copy/pasted the following in my 'head' and nothing has changed.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please share your entire code here. if you see above example and run snippet code it is working.

Comment: @Lil'BigBoy i see you are using classes of bootstrap 4 and included boostrap 3 please correct.

Comment: @Lil'BigBoy correct include on your page should be as follows.

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: i have corrected code in my answer itself pick it and your navigation should work. @Lil'BigBoy

Answer (score 0):

In question the classes which you have used relates to latest version of bootstrap. You should use the latest version.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>White Rose Crew Company Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutUs">ABOUT US</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#ourWork">OUR WORK</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#theCrew">THE CREW</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contactUs">CONTACT US</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        </main>
      
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    </body>
</html>
```